# Copying a formula or function down a column of 1000 rows?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

How can you copy a formula down a column in sheets? Not by manually dragging it. Imagine there are 1000 rows. Is there a short cut?

I have dragged the corner of the cell, but that works for a shorter list. Sometimes when I put the formula in the cell Sheets will ask if it can auto-fill, which is great but if you edit that formula - I can't seem to copy the new edit formula down 1000 rows without having to manually drag the corner.

Comment: Most often, there is a way to write *one* formula total that will process the entire column without any dragging at all. If you care to share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), I or another volunteer contributor here can take a look and see if your particular drag-down formula can be rewritten as an *array formula*. If so, any changes you'd ever need to make would be to that one formula only.

Answer (score 6):

example 1:

you enter value/formula into A2 and want to fill down all the way.

1. select cell A2
2. press <kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd></kbd>
3. then press <kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd></kbd>

---

example 2:

you enter value/formula into A2 and want to fill down only few cells.

1. select cell A2
2. press <kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd></kbd> to select desired cells
3. then press <kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd></kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the first row, then press CTRL+SHIFT+↓ until the last row and paste it.